# Converting Checked items from CheckedListBox to String then store it to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

Newbie here in VB. Is there any easy or simple way to convert 5 checked items in my checkedlistbox into string so that I can save save them in mySQL database? or something that is more simpler? My code goes like this so far.

```
Try
        cnn.Open()
        com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM columns WHERE cname ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", cnn)
        cdr = com.ExecuteReader
        If cdr.HasRows Then
            cdr.Close()
            cnn.Close()
            MsgBox("This Table has already been created!")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        cdr.Close()
        com = New MySqlCommand("INSERT into column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, cname) VALUES('" ??? "', '" & TextBox1.Text &"')", cnn)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
        MsgBox("Attendance Table has been created.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cnn.Close()
        End If
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

I'm stuck right now on what to put in VALUES after the INSERT MySQLCommand. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error ?

Your MySQL Command looks wrong ( One with INSERT ), or is that ok ?

Comment: It's the problem, I don't know what to put in that "???" area. The problem is I need to store the 5 items I checked in the checklistbox into my database but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This should return the checked items in checked list box as a comma separated string.

```
Private Function getChkdBoxString() As String
    Dim myChkdBoxes = CheckedListBox.CheckedItems 'rename CheckedListBox to the name of the checked list box that you have used
    Dim chkBoxString As String = ""
    For Each chkBox In myChkdBoxes
        chkBoxString = chkBox.ToString & "," & chkBoxString
    Next
    Return chkBoxString
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for this code. But I'd like to ask on how can I actually insert this into my database. Pardon me for being a newbie, I'm a bit  confused

Answer (score 0):

use this code, is simple but worked for me:

on your click event add:

```
    Dim mycheckedlist = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    Dim checkedstr As String = ""

    For Each chkBox In mycheckedlist
    checkedstr = chkBox.ToString & "," & checkedstr


    Next

    (here you add your code to insert the checkstr 
    variable as a string into your database)
```

this way you get comma separated list of values as a string.